# HTML5 multiselect dropdown with checkboxes plugin. Designed as standard <select> dropdown

Tags: multi-select

I have been looking around all day after a good multiselect plugin looks as the same as a standard dropdown control. I have tried using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget created by ehynds, dropdown-check-list and jQuery MultiSelect created by A Beautiful Site. These are really good plugins but I really want to use a plugin that have the same appearence as a standard dropdown in html5. Hope I make any sence!

Have a nice day!

// Solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bootstrap Multiselect -
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

In terms of appearance, you may have to use CSS to get the styling you want.

Comment: This is a better choice in my opinion. I'll make this the answer so those looking for a multiselect finds this example. Thanks!

Comment: Was looking for nice search filters for my project.This is perfect .Thanks for sharing .

Comment: It uses jquery and I want to avoid using jquery

Answer (score 4):

Because of many have looked for an answear to my question I will show a good script.
Im very fond of: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/

Answer (score 2):

http://users.skavt.net/blaz/MultiSelect/demo.html

Answer (score -7):

There is an easier way I found today that will allow users to select multiple options in the `<select>` element. The [multiple attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) specifies that multiple options can be selected at once.

```
<select multiple>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The user asking the question is asking looking for a way to style the multiselect and seems to be aware of how to implement plain multiselect