# How to use Checkbox inside Select options in Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, knockout.js

Hi I want to add checkbox for all the options in dropdown.

My HTML is like this -

```html
<div class="multi-select-dd-list"> 
    <div id="checkboxes" class="patient-list-selection">                
      <select class="patient-list-select specialty-list-left" data-bind="options : specialtiesList, optionsText : 'name'">
      </select>
    </div> 
</div>
```

So here I am binding specialtiesList.

What I want is a way to use checkbox before each option of the dropdown.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The standard select widget is not very customizable. You will need a replacement widget. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026321/html5-multiselect-dropdown-with-checkboxes-plugin-designed-as-standard-select

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code implementing the same. I think you are looking something like this.

**.js, .css and .html file**

```js
function CheckableBox(label, isChecked) {
  this.label = label;
  this.isChecked = ko.observable(isChecked || false);
}

function ViewModel() {
  this.items = [
    new CheckableBox("First", true),
    new CheckableBox("Second", true),
    new CheckableBox("Third")
  ];
  
  this.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();

 /* Includes only the checked items */
  this.tempSelection = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.isChecked();
    });
  }, this);
  
  /* Builds a comma separated string of selected items */
  this.selectedItemsStr = ko.pureComputed(function() {
   var str = this.selectedItems()
     .map(function(item) {
       return item.label;
      })
      .join(", ")
      
      return str || "-- No options selected --";
  }, this);
  
  /* Determines whether the selectable options are displayed. */
  this.optionsShown = ko.observable(false);
  
  this.optionsShown.subscribe(function() {
   this.updateSelections();
  }, this);
  
  this.confirmSelection();
};

ViewModel.prototype.toggleOptions = function() {
 this.optionsShown(!this.optionsShown());
};

ViewModel.prototype.confirmSelection = function() {
 this.selectedItems(this.tempSelection());
  this.closeOptions();
};

ViewModel.prototype.closeOptions = function() {
  this.optionsShown(false);
}

ViewModel.prototype.updateSelections = function() {
 var selection = this.selectedItems();
  this.items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.isChecked(~selection.indexOf(item));
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main-container {
  width: 400px;
}

.main-container,
.select-container {
  position: relative;
}

.select-container {
  height: 2em;
}

select,
.select-container::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.select-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display: block;
}

.options-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
}

.options-container.shown {
  display: block;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: .2em;
}

label:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.checked {
  background: #568ECB;
  color: white;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background: #F6F6F6;
}

.button-container button {
  margin: .4em;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="select-container" data-bind="click: toggleOptions">
    <select data-bind="options: [selectedItemsStr]"></select>
  </div>
  <div class="options-container" data-bind="css: { 'shown': optionsShown }">
    <div class="options" data-bind="foreach: items">
      <label data-bind="css: { 'checked': isChecked }">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
        <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <button type="button" data-bind="click: confirmSelection">OK</button>
      <button type="button" data-bind="click: closeOptions">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not forget to upvote if I answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select').material_select();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
     
     <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please include a little explanation of what you're doing. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques

Comment: this is base code for add check box in option drop down using materialize css

Comment: I meant you should edit your answer to include some plain English text saying how you were solving the problem. Note that the OP is asking about using Knockout, which you are not using.